# Función *arg no hace nada

Tags: python

resulta que para un ejercicio tengo que escribir una función que tome argumentos(por ser *arg me imagino que tuplas) generados arbitrariamente y retorne la suma de esos argumentos. Hago la siguiente operación y no me tira error pero tampoco pasa nada.

```
def suma_de_argumentos(*arg):
    sum(arg)
    suma_de_argumentos(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Algunas observaciones:

- Hay que quitar los espacios delante de `suma_de_argumentos(1,2,3,4,5)` para que no forma parte de la función.
- La función tendría que retornar un resultado (o imprimir algo) para tener sentido.
- Después de capturar el resultado, también habría que hacer algo con este resultado. Por ejemplo, imprimirlo.

```py
def suma_de_argumentos(*arg):
    return sum(arg)

resultado = suma_de_argumentos(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
print(resultado)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente se te ha olvidado el `return`. Tu función suma los argumentos, pero no los asigna a ninguna variable ni los devuelve.

```
def suma_de_argumentos(*arg):
    return sum(arg)
suma_de_argumentos(1,2,3,4,5)
```